# I installed bootable windows 10 on my usb and lost all my previous files on the usb. How do I recover them?

Tags: boot, usb, data-recovery

I installed bootable windows 10 on my usb and lost all my previous files on the usb.

[image]

Yes, I forgot to back the previous files.
How do I recover them?

Comment: What size is your USB stick? Windows installer wants about 8GB, so rationally you may have recoverable data of size equal or less than the difference between 8GB & your USB size. BTW, it is extremely unwise to ever keep the only copy of any data on a USB or SD drive. They have a remarkable fail-rate at the best of times.

Comment: @Tetsujin The size of my USB stick is 64GB. (And yes, I know that it is unwise to keep the only copy of data on a USB drive, this happened because I was transferring my data from my old pc to my new pc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The installer has not only overwritten the allocation table, but also the actual space on the drive those files once occupied. You *might* be able to recover some of the original data, at least from the free space, using [Recuva](https://www.ccleaner.com/recuva) or similar tool.

A professional data recovery company probably would still be able to retrieve the overwritten data, but that's a *very* expensive process.

---

*Updated as Silbee pointed out the shortcoming in the original answer*

Comment: So that means that I cannot recover the previous files?

Comment: While peregrino is correct, you have effectively overwritten alot of data already, there might still be some recoverable files on there. There's a plethora of tools you can try (commercial and free) to try and recover files. 'Recuva' would be a good place to start.